# Audio quiz with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'd like to create a simple quiz with Tkinter (Python 2.7). I have a list of audios and for each of them I want to have the following:

1. A *button* that reproduces the audio.
2. An *entry* where the user can introduce any text.
3. A *label* displaying "Incorrect" by default and "Correct!" whenever the text in the entry is the title of the song in the audio.

I managed to create the three objects, but I'm having a hard time trying to update the label according to the entry text: there are many references around but I couldn't get it working. I guess I do not understand well how the loop works and when events are triggered.

Could you please provide a minimal example that does what I intend to? I provide my code below, but it is very likely to be bloated (I'm totally novice to Tkinter and to object oriented programming) since I basically built it from an existing example in the Internet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#encoding=utf-8

import Tkinter as tk
import vlc

tk.Tk()
var_entry= tk.StringVar()
var_label= tk.StringVar()

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):

        self.audio= tk.Button(self,text='Play Audio',command=lambda:vlc.MediaPlayer('./audios/my_audio.mp3').play())
        self.audio.grid()

        self.entry = tk.Entry(self,width=50,textvariable=var_entry)
        self.entry.grid()

        var_label.set('Correct!\n' if var_entry.get()=='my_audio_title' else 'Incorrect\n')
        self.label = tk.Label(self,textvariable=var_label)
        self.label.grid()

        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit',command=self.quit)
        self.quitButton.grid()

app = Application()
app.master.title('Audio Quiz')
app.mainloop()
```

I'm sure that the line starting by `var_label.set` is missplaced, but I don't really know where I should write it and how to make the update for the label.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show what you have tried, even if it does not work, we will try to correct you, so you learn more than just copying the answer.

Comment: I may not have explained myself: what I tried is the code I provide above. What I meant is that I took a non-related simple Tkinter example I found around (this one: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/minimal-app.html) as a model.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`trace`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) to achieve:

> *A label displaying "Incorrect" by default and "Correct!" whenever the text in the entry is the title of the song in the audio.*

When `trace` is used with `'w'` option, it calls a method whenever the variable class(`BooleanVar`, `DoubleVar`, `IntVar`, `StringVar`) it is attached to is re-written. Below is an example checking whether the text in the entry is `"Valid String"` or not:

```
import tkinter as tk

def check_entry(*args):
    global entry, entry_var, label
    if entry_var.get() == "Valid String":
        label['text'] = "Correct"
    else:
        label['text'] = "Incorrect"

root = tk.Tk()

entry_var = tk.StringVar()

label = tk.Label(root)
entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=entry_var)

label.pack()
entry.pack()

entry_var.trace('w', check_entry)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, Nae. This is exactly the functionality I needed. However, I'll have several audios and it would be great to have a single check_entry function that works for all of them. Do you know how to achieve it?

Comment: @A.Bellmunt Sure. You just need to save the `audio_name` in a global variable when it starts being played and then replace `"Valid String"` with `audio_name`.